# Withdrawing funds from ETH Mainnet wallet

Tags: mainnet, withdrawal

I have some ETH in a wallet (on an NFT platform) on the Mainnet network. I also have a MetaMask wallet on Mainnet and a Binance account.

I would like to withdraw my funds to my fiat bank account. It seems the way to do this is to send my ETH from that wallet to Binance to withdraw. However, there is no Mainnet option under Crypto Deposit in Binance.

What's the best way to withdraw funds that are on Mainnet? Should I swap the ETH for BTC in MetaMask first?

(Apologies for the basic question, but I have been burned before after sending to the wrong address.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't swap ETH for BTC on a decentralized exchange because those two crypto-currencies are on two different blockchains.
Metamask swap uses multiple decentralized exchanges. What you can have by using the swap function of Metamask is WrappedBTC which is an ERC20 token located on Ethereum.

What you can do is directly send your ETH to a centralized exchange (as Binance). There is a "deposit" part. You will then have an Ethereum address. From your Metamask, you will have to send eth to this address.

Answer (score 0):

Ethereum(ERC20) is the mainnet.